# Android week number wrong for phone but not Emulator

Tags: android, calendar, numbers

I have a program where it relies heavily on identifying the week number for the year.  I have done the leg work and figured out all the problems that will cause and settle with this method.  I works perfect for years that have 53 weeks and such.  My only issue is that when I run it on my emulator for 2.2 it works perfect, like this is week 19 and its correct.  when I run it on my phone a G1, the week shows 20.  How do I fix this?

Here is my week code:

```
/**
 * Format the date into a number that is the year*100 plus the week i.e. 2008 and its week 11
 * would show as 811
 * @param - String of a date to create a week id, must be in format of 2011-01-31 (YYYY-MM-DD)
 * @return returns next weeks id
 */
public static int getWeekId(String date){

    // Set the first day of week to Monday and set the starting new year weeks
    // as a full first week in the new year.
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);

    if (!date.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        String[] token = date.split("-", 3);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(token[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(token[1])-1; // months are 0-11 stupid..
        int day = Integer.parseInt(token[2]);
        c.set(year, month, day);
    }


    int yearWeek = ( (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 2000)*100 + (c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)));

    Log.d("getWeekId()"," WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

    return yearWeek;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'd leave this in a comment, but my account does not yet have commenting permissions.)

When called with 2011-01-01, the code currently returns 1152.  Is this as intended?

Comment: I do some post processing on that to figure out years properly, the yearWeek will actually be 1052.  The first week this year starts on Jan 03 and Jan 1st and 2nd are in the 52nd week of 2010.  With that said the main issue is on 2.2 its week 19 for today and on my G1(1.6) its week 20.  What's the deal and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there is likely more intricacy to it than you've written. I don't say this to be mean, it's just that there are probably lots of interesting weird cases that you haven't considered. There is a good Java library that knows a ton of stuff about times, and may have this code written already, Check it out: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes I understand the intricacy of the Java time and have been running this version of the Java code for years now on linux servers.  I ported some of this to android now and I am getting this issue with week number being wrong on certain phones.  I understand joda has something but I am trying to keep the install package down to a minimum and not having to deal with licensing issues of 3rd party products, even open source.  Looks like I will have to do a work around by using the webservice to hand me the week number.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently its a bug in the android phone...so watch out for this when using android 1.6.